# Print/Export Attribute Table in Form View (QGIS 2.10.1)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, printing

Is there a means or available plugin which works to enable a direct print of the attribute table in form view?

I recall this feature was on many a wishlist back around 2.6, but I'm unaware if the issue has been addressed.